# Laravel Passport not able to install on laravel 5.4.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

Hi I am new to laravel and trying to install the Laravel passport on an existing laravel project. I am trying to run this command

`composer require Laravel/passport`

When I run the command it shows `nothing to install or update`. But, I can see that in my composer I have Laravel `version ~4.0` and I am using PHP7.1. I have also installed one of its dependency `illuminator/encryption=5.4.36`.

Can somebody help me out? How to install my Laravel passport?

I am running laravel 5.4.36 (it's locked)

PS: Had to remove composer file content.

Comment: You already have laravel passport. If you want to check what packages you had you can run `composer update` to see what packages you installed.

Comment: Yes, the package is somehow showing in the composer but it's is not installed and not showing up anywhere in the project.

Answer (score 3):

You have already installed Laravel Passport. Your composer / console returns that message because its already downloaded.

Your composer.json tells you that you downloaded version 4.0:

```
    "laravel/passport": "~4.0",
```

Now you just have to move on I recommened going through the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport).

There is also a nice tutorial from Taylow Otwell regarding Laravel Passport.

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

Comment: I will check it one more time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get started, install Passport via the Composer package manager:

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

Next, register the Passport service provider in the providers array of your config/app.php configuration file:

```
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

then the command line again type:

```
php artisan migrate
```

For more info look: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport